# Python: The confusion of value assignment in 2-dimension list

Tags: python-3.x

I define a two-dimension array in python like this:

```
a = [[1]*3]*3
```

and I want to assign one element to be 2, like:

```
a[1][1] = 2
```

However, a turns out to be:

```
[[1,2,1],[1,2,1],[1,2,1]]
```

Instead of what I thought like this:

```
[[1,1,1],[1,2,1],[1,1,1]]
```

Anyone has any idea?

[The ScreenShot of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjBfY.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using list comprehension:

```
a=[[1 for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(3)]

a
Out[32]: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]

a[1][1]=2

a
Out[34]: [[1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Comment: Yeah, I find this method works, thanks a lot! And I have found the real reason in another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think that having brackets inside brackets is making a None value item at 0 and that it is multiplying/unpacking the inside multiplication first, so that your reference a[1][1] is referring to the meta list [[1,1 1]*3]and coming up with the second element of the the second element of that switching it to 2 before the second multiplication takes place, because of order of operations.